# Registering ModelBinders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I have just updated to RC1 MVC from the beta product.

I have the following code in my Application_start (in the global.ascx)

```
System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(Shared.DO.Gig)] = new GigModelBinder();
```

This results in the following exception....

> Method not found: 
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2 System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.get_Binders()'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you re-built your project.  Binders is a ModelBinderDictionary, its not a IDictionary, quite possibly it was before RC1.

Comment: Yeah - I rebuilt. How are we supposed to register the Binders now?

Comment: The code looks ok to me assuming GigModelBinder implements IModelBinder.  The error you were getting indicated an older definition of ModelBinders was being used.

Comment: Do you nean that my ModelBinders themselves (i.e. GigModelBinder) is out of date? They are in the format defined in the beta version of MVC?

Comment: I don't know what you GigModelBinder does or how its built so I can't tell whether its out-of-date.  All I do know at this point is the definition of ModelBinders property has changed.  If your binder implements IModelBinder that line of code should work.